# Relative order of elements in list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm writing a function that takes in a list of integers and returns a list of relative positioned elements.

That is to say, if my input into said function is *[1, 5, 4]* the output would be *[0, 2, 1]*, since 1 is the lowest element, 5 is the highest and 4 in the middle, all elements are unique values, or a *set()*

But code speaks, the function i have so far is

```
def relative_order(a):
    rel=[]
    for i in a:
        loc = 0
        for v in a:
            if i > v:
                loc += 1
        rel.append(loc)
    return rel
```

It does work, but since i'm sending big lists into this function, and i have to compare each element to all elements in each iteration it's taking ~5sec with a list of 10.000 elements.

My question is how can i improve the speed on said function and maybe be a bit more Pythonic, i tried comprehension lists, but my Python skills are lacking and i only came up with an imperative way of implementing this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be written as a list comprehension like this:

```
lst = [1, 5, 4]
s = sorted(lst)    
[s.index(x) for x in lst]
=> [0, 2, 1]
```

And here's another test, using @frb's example:

```
lst = [10, 2, 3, 9]
s = sorted(lst)    
[s.index(x) for x in lst]
=> [3, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I still don't like it for performance reasons, but I removed my downvote.

Comment: @Volatility OP specified that there are no repeated elements, so that's not going to be a problem

Comment: @nightcracker well to be fair the speed improved from 4.54sec to 0.52sec using this one.

Comment: @HashCollision my pleasure! a bit tricky to get right, but here you go :)

Comment: Just coming back to this - I deleted my answer because frb showed it was incorrect. I phrased my previous comment very poorly - I meant to say I don't like the performance of this answer (but I very much like the answer itself - it's conceptually clear, which is very important). To make up you get a +1 :) The runtime of this answer is O(n^2), which is pretty bad for large lists. If performance were important I would probably do a decorate-sort-undecorate construction, but I'm not sure how performant that is in Python.

Comment: @nightcracker I was thinking the same - so I've done that creating a dict of value->index, then mapping over that to get the indices... I'm strangely re-assured we both came up with the same wrong answer originally though ;)

Comment: -1, I would argue it is more pythonic and certainly faster to use numpy.argsort. This would also avoid an intermediate sorted list in memory which is not needed.

Comment: @akk numpy is not always available, and using it introduces an additional dependency in the code. Using the base libraries is more pythonic, or else you'd find that _all_ the answers in SO that require sorting would use numpy ... and they don't.

Comment: @akk besides, `numpy.argsort([10, 2, 3, 9])` returns `[1, 2, 3, 0]`, which is the wrong answer. Please reconsider your downvote, it's unjustified.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yep argsort does indeed give a different result as I have now mentioned in my answer.

Comment: about the downvote, I have decided to stick with it and give +1 to JonClements' answer, as his method avoids the costly index operation and should have higher prominence.

Comment: @akk while I appreciate the upvote, I would also point out that downvoting a working answer (even if it's not the most efficient version) is somewhat contrary to the spirit of SO - if you don't think the answer is deserving of an upvote that you don't need to upvote it, but I certainly see no reason to downvote it. Need I point out that your answer is actually incorrect (there's several deleted answers on this question that also made similar assumptions - myself included) - yet no one has chosen to downvote yours...

Comment: @JonClements - I think the best answer (your one) should be top of the list - therefore people who view the page will have the best response. For me that is the spirit of SO. Downvoting is nothing personal. In relation to my answer - as I show in my answer I have shown the 'classic' way of sorting a list via indexing, so much so their is a custom function in numpy to do exactly that via argsort. Sometimes people ask the wrong question and for the good of the community I am merely catering for that case...

Comment: Is there a way to assign different resulting values (order of the elements) when there are duplicate values? For example, if the input is `[10, 2, 9, 9]`, I'd prefer the output to be `[3, 0, 1, 2]` or `[3, 0, 2, 1]` (order-preserving would be better than the opposite, or random), rather than `[3, 0, 1, 1]` as it is now.

Comment: @ceilingcat see the answer with the most votes after my own

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I just tried it (@JonClements 's answer, right?). Doesn't seem to work either. `[10, 2, 9, 9]` => `[3, 0, 2, 2]`, but I want `[3, 0, 1, 2]`.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another go that should be more efficient that keeping `.index`'ing into the list as it's stated that no duplicate values will occur, so we can do the lookup O(1) instead of linear... (and actually meets the requirements):

```
>>> a = [10, 2, 3, 9]
>>> indexed = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(sorted(a))}
>>> map(indexed.get, a)
[3, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: +1 : more efficient than my answer. But I'd rather use this instead of `map`: `[indexed[x] for x in a]`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez fair enough - I just used `map` as that with a builtin function *should* be faster than a list-comp

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Having said that - I'm getting the opposite results that I would expect... umm....

Comment: what do you mean? which was faster, then?

Comment: Go figure ... and my answer, how does it fare? if you're benchmarking, please post the results ;)

Comment: @JonClements List comprehensions leave more freedom to the Python peephole optimizer than map - it's actually quite common to see a map get outperformed by comprehensions.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez 1.4 usecs

Comment: @nightcracker I normally have experienced the opposite ;) - but good idea

Comment: @ÓscarLópez `map(indexed.get, a)` is 87.7usec, `[indexed[x] for x in a]` is 104usec and `[s.index(x) for x in a]` is 9.2msec... That's based on a range of 1,000 unique integers (randomly shuffled)

Comment: @JonClements Haha! Big-O wins again.

Answer (score 1):

The method you have a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ takes order n^2 time.

This should work in log(n) time:

> ```
> def relative_order(a):
>     positions = sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i])
>     return sorted(range(len(a)), key = lambda i: positions[i])
> ```

It's still order log(n) and so should work for your large lists too.

Edit:

Outside of lambda.

Comment: That is not O(log(n)).

Comment: Sorting is `O(n log n)`

Comment: This answer was an epic fail

Answer (score 1):

```
def relative_order(a):
    l = sorted(a)
    # hash table of element -> index in ordered list
    d = dict(zip(l, range(len(l))))
    return [d[e] for e in a]

print relative_order([1, 5, 4])
print relative_order([2, 3, 1])
print relative_order([10, 2, 3, 9])

[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
[3, 0, 1, 2]
```

the algorithm should be as efficient as sort, but use additional space.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is about sorting. I would recommend the use of Numpy or 'Numeric Python'. Numpy is a Python module that is optimised for "fast, compact, multidimensional array faciliities". It is the package of choice for scientific computing in Python. http://www.numpy.org/

```
import numpy as np

input_array = np.array([1, 5, 4])
sorted_indices = np.argsort(input_array)

print sorted_indices
#[0 2, 1]
```

I have also added profiler output based on an array of size `50000`. It shows this method is (around 4x) faster than using the Python `sorted` function as per earlier answers.

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

    1    0.009    0.009    0.009    0.009 {method 'argsort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    1    0.034    0.034    0.034    0.034 {sorted}
```

**Warning:**
Commentary suggested the answer is not inline with the authors function. This is true. I guess the whole point of argsort is that:

```
sorted_array = input_array[sorted_indices]
```

gives you a sorted array.

The OP is, curious to my mind, asking for a result which requires a sorted array to be available via:

```
for i, val in enumerate(sorted_indices):
    sorted_array[val] = input_array[i]
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `np.argsort(np.array([10, 2, 3, 9]))` returns `array([1, 2, 3, 0])`, but the correct answer is `array([3, 0, 1, 2])`

Comment: you did not get the question right, take a look and run all the other answers. Look: If the input list were sorted 10 would be at the index 3, 2 at index 0, 3 at index 1 and 9 at index 2. That's what OP is asking, that's what my answer does.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended my answer

Comment: Bummer, I am actually looking for the way to do this in numpy